# How to force UDP Packets to be capsulated over TCP for Cloud Gaming? (VPN TCP Tunnel, Packetloss fix)

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, vpn, packet-loss

I have a question about packetloss in streaming (UDP protocoll) and I have packetloss with every Cloud-Gaming streaming provider and the only workaround is a VPN with TCP as protocoll.

The problem is that here in Germany the peering is totally bad so UDP packets on the way have problems to be transmitted properly.

VPN with TCP as a protocol creates help here by packing the UDP packets in a TCP frame (I think) and then routing them.

As soon as I switch the VPN off or back to UDP I have packetloss again, TCP is the only way I can get rid of the streaming problem, unfortunately one can't select TCP as protocoll in the settings of the cloud providers, so I have to rely on VPN with TCP.

Sadly the ping and the response time increases a lot, because the route is extended and therefore overhead is created.

Are there other ways to force streaming over TCP? Maybe via Windows GPO/Registry or router settings?

I don't want to rely on VPNs, as they cost money and improve the experience in general, but don't solve the problem overall.

Comment: UDP is a message-based protocol, not a streaming protocol like TCP. Using UDP means you accept the fact that you _will_ lose datagrams as there are no guarantees with UDP. When you send a UDP datagram, you have no expectation that it will reach its destination. If you need guarantees, then you use TCP or deal with it using an application-layer protocol.

Comment: "_Sadly the ping and the response time increases a lot, because the route is extended and therefore overhead is created._" Ping uses ICMP, which is a completely different protocol than TCP or UDP. Ping times only measure ICMP and have no relationship to how TCP or UDP perform.